# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::extend()

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I updated my project Laravel version from 5.8 to 9 and found the error:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::extend()

I updated Laravel from version 5.8 to version 8. However, the new version introduced a new authentication method. I encountered some errors during the update, but I managed to resolve them. However, I am now facing this specific error and I'm unable to proceed.

Comment: Go to [Upgrading To 6.0 From 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#upgrade-6.0), and after keep going to the next versions until you found the deprecation warning.